How can I create subscriptions after the manual payment is received?
I'm creating a site where I want to allow users to purchase subscriptions, which they pay for by cheque or bank transfer, after being sent an invoice. After the payment has been received, an administrator will update the order to show that payment has been received, and at this point I want the subscription to be created.
I have followed the instructions for commerce_recurring and created a product variation type with the Allow Subscriptions trait, and a product variation with a Subscription Type of Product Variation, and a Billing Schedule which is Prepaid and Rolling. I have the payment gateway "Manual", which uses the Manual plugin.
When a user completes the checkout, no subscription is created - which is correct. But no subscription is created when the payment is marked as received either.
It looks like the Commerce Recurring module doesnt support manual payment for subscriptions. I found a few issues that appear relevant to this:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring/issues/2919602
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring/issues/3189954
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring/issues/2929902
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring/issues/3203545

I tried applying the patches provided, but none of these deal with my particular case.
After some hunting around, it looks to me as though I will need to implement an event listener to listen for the OrderEvents::ORDER_PAID event, and then create the subscription (using code similar to lines 103-130 of commerce_recurring/src/EventSubscriber/OrderSubscriber.php).
Is that the right way to do it, or is there a better way? And will there be any other events that I need to look out for and handle? (Like Order_Refunded, perhaps?)
I'm using Drupal 10.4.0 with Commerce 3.0.0-beta2 and Commerce_Recurring 1.0.0-rc3.

Are all of the subscriptions paid for by cheque or bank transfer?  In other words, does an admin manually enable all subscriptions?

Customers can opt to pay by card or have an invoice sent. If they pay by card, then the subscription is created correctly at checkout. If they opt for an invoice, then an administrator will manually update the order once payment has been received.
